# Website with a very slow load time on every page

Tags: performance, wordpress

http://www.puppykisses.org/

i made a WordPress page for a client, and for some reason it is taking over a minute to load the page. The only thing that I could think of being the problem is the amount of photos that he inserted into the slider up top on the home page. It looks like all those pictures need to load before anything else pops up. But then I click on Contact or any other page that has no real images to speak of, and the problem is still there. Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to fix this. thanks!

Comment: The ungodly amount of photos in that gallery sure isn't helping, but it looks like the problem is largely on the server side since it takes so long to even start downloading the page.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the files that are causing the issue. I would definitely create a support ticket with the hosting company to see if it's something they can sort out or diagnose.

Comment: According to the net tab in FireBug, it's the initial GET request that's taking upwards of a minute, not any of the subsequent resource loads afterward.  Might be worth putting in some logging in the server-side code to see how long any given discrete step takes, perhaps to narrow down where the problem is happening?

Comment: Get page speed insights extension for chrome. It breaks down the load and tells you what is taking the most time, and what you should focus on speeding up.

Comment: The problem is Comic Sans.

Answer (score 0):

Like @David said, its the initial request (the source for the page) that is giving you the issues.   This means it is unlikely an issue with hosting, and most likely an issue with your code.  I would go through any plugins you have installed and disable them one-by-one, and slowly start commenting out your own custom dynamic code bit by bit, till you see what is taking so incredibly long.  Then rewrite/excise that code from the site.

Comment: And not meant to be a flame, im sure a client decided it was a good idea, but pinks/reds are a __BIG__ no no in web design.  As people get older their corneas get very sensitive to those colors (when they come from a backlit screen).  So having a bright pink background is going to burn the eyes of most 40+ year olds

Comment: i feel the same way. but this was exactly what she wanted. I have learned thru web design that arguing with the client that is paying you is a BIGGER no no than the eye physiology of potential clients.

Comment: @DustinMyers: Sounds like you were hired by a subsidiary of Boyd's Toast: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/design_hell

Comment: @David yea, hahaha. i had my input and the initial design was a lot more solid. but she wanted it to appeal to women, and loved the idea of hot pink. i tried originally to dull down the pink, but she was very into a brighter bink. i at least tried to balance it a little bit with the complimentary blue in the background where she originally had wanted pink as well.

Comment: Lol thats exactly the comic i was thinking of hahaha

Answer (score 0):

**Start With the Basics**

- Keep the number of WordPress plugins you use to a minimum
- Get a Proper Hosting Provider
- Remove Unnecessary Code From WordPress Header -> http://goo.gl/yfRcF
- Use firebug and click Network tab to check loading speed for each files
- Check Suggestion how to improve website speed -> http://goo.gl/FtiX3
- Install WP Super Cache plugin -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/

**If you use gallery try to use image thumbnail rather than load whole images size*